# Can't put a form in multiple divs

Tags: html, css

I have an accordion menu on my page which spans across multiple divs, and I tried to put it in a form like below

(Note that the code within the divs is very long, so I removed it. It works perfectly fine without the form element.) If I put everything inside a form, nothing seems to display properly anymore, and if it helps, here is my CSS.

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  font-family: Montserrat;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <button class="accordion"></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <input class="input name" type="text" name="name1" placeholder="name">
    <input class="input name" type="text" name="name2" placeholder="last name">
    <select class="drop">
      <option selected hidden>choose</option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
    </select>
    <select class="drop">
      <option selected hidden>choose</option>
      <option></option>
      <option></option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="date">
    <input class="input name" type="tel" pattern="0[0-9]{9}" placeholder="phone number">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="current">
      <label for="current">currently active</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion"></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="birth code">
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="county">
    <br>
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="city">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="address">
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="birthplace">
  </div>
  <button class="accordion"></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="bank name">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="account code">
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="account name">
  </div>
  <button class="accordion"></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="id code">
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="id given on">
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="id given by">
    <br>
    <input class="input name" type="text" placeholder="hire date">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="contract number">
  </div>
  <button class="accordion"></button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Placeholder Text</p>
  </div>
  <input class="button" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do and what the issue is

Comment: I have an accordion menu (multiple collapsible sections) where each section contains a handful of inputs, and I want to make it a working form, but when I put it inside a <form> element, nothing displays correctly anymore.

Comment: Impossible to see the issue because you removed the form fields from your code

Comment: i edited it and now everything is shown, i thought it would be irrelevant since everything is displayed perfectly fine without the form

Comment: When I checked it removing css file, it worked fine with form. It seems that this happens becuase of the "accordion" class you have.

Comment: Where is the code that changes max-height: 0; to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` elements have a `type` attribute. The default (what you get if, as you do, omit it) is `type="submit"`.

When a `<button type="submit">` **inside a `<form>`** is clicked, the form gets **submitted**. This leads to a full page (re-)load, which destroys any Javascript state the page had before the click.

To fix your problem, use the correct button type, which for you is `<button type="button">`.

Comment: But also the panels needs their max-height: 0; changed on click of the button

Comment: OP: *everything is displayed perfectly fine without the form* that's why I didn't look any further.

Comment: I do not see any fields in chrome in the above snippet